# What should be entered in the campaign field when importing a CSV file?

Tags: custom-fields, import

I'm trying to import a CSV file with donations that need to be linked with a certain campaign. I tried putting the campaign name, then the external id, and even just "matching" but all of them are generating an error. Any advice?

I am running CiviCRM 4.6.19 on Drupal. The error message is:

> 'xyz' is not a valid option for field campaign_id

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Exchange! You can help us help you by giving us more information.  Could you please edit your question a) to include the error that you're seeing?  Also the CMS you're using (Drupal, WordPress, Joomla, Backdrop) and your CiviCRM version?  Thanks!  I'll post a partial answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to successfully import the campaign on a contribution by importing the campaign's CiviCRM ID.

I agree that it seems odd that campaigns have an "External ID" field, but it can't be used for imports, though!

You can find your campaign IDs by going to **Campaigns menu » Dashboard » Campaigns**.  In CiviCRM 4.7+, they'll be in the first column of the list.  See screenshot 1 below.  If you're using CiviCRM 4.6 or lower, you can find the ID by hovering your mouse over the "Edit" button next to a campaign and reading the ID that appears in the URL at the bottom of your web browser.  See screenshot 2 below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you please clarify where i would find the CiviCRM ID? (Sorry if its obvious, I'm a newbie.)

Comment: Stack Exchange is for newbies!  I updated the question to answer you.  If you have just a couple of different campaigns in your import, this is a quick find-and-replace job in Excel.  If you have hundreds of campaigns, this is going to get annoying quickly.  If that's the case, leave a comment (or find me on chat.civicrm.org) and we'll get into your options.

Comment: Thanks! Cant figure out how to attach a screenshot but I dont have that column on my dashboard. Just starts with the Title column. What am I missing? Thank for your help!

Comment: @Nomi Hmm - apparently that column is only in Civi 4.7.  I just updated the question with instructions for Civi 4.6!

Answer (score -1):

Is the campaign currently active or was it started before the dates your importing? I'm just throwing out a possible reason why it fails. I do not know if this would make or break the import.

Comment: Yes its both currently active and and the dates should not conflict.